# Problem in Creating Link in React using router dom

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I have tried to create a link through Link of react-router-dom. My code is as
Follow:

Header.js File

class Header extends Component
{

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)


    this.state={
        title:'Welcome',
        
    }
}  

render(){
    return(
    <React.Fragment>
        <header>
            
            <h2> {this.state.title} </h2>
             <Link to="/">Home</Link>
             <Link to="/Artist">Artist</Link>
             <Link to="/Movies"> Movies</Link>   
          
        </header>
        <hr/>
        
        

    </React.Fragment>



    )
}
```

}

Routing.js

```
const Routing =()=>{
return(
    <BrowserRouter >
    <center>
    <Header/>             
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route path='/Movies' component={Movies}/>
    <Route path='/Artist' component={Artist}/>
    <Footer year="2020"/>
    </center>
    </BrowserRouter>


)
```

When I try to Run Code It Gives The Following Warning.Please help me out to solve this.

This is Warning I am Getting

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check your code at Header.js:24.
    in Header (at Routing.js:13)
    in center (at Routing.js:12)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at Routing.js:11)
    in Routing (at src/index.js:12)
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and your error message please ?

Comment: can you write the code in codesandbox for reference

Comment: This may be of help since you have not included any codes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136028/what-exactly-is-switch-used-for-in-react-router/60137200#60137200

Comment: I have Updated the post and added code now  @HamzaKhattabi

Comment: @RaghvenderKataria

Comment: Post the code don't attach a picture of it.

Comment: Code is Also Posted, Help me out@GrantSingleton